# Find all optimal solutions by Simplex

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Let "stable operation" be an operation on a simplex tableau such that the entering variable has a reduced cost of 0. Recall that a pivoting operation will not change the objective value if either the reduced cost (i.e. in the $\bar c$ row shown below) is 0, or if the leaving variable has value 0 already.

**Example of stable operation (which preserves objective value):**
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc|c}
\text{Basis} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & \text{Sol.} \\
\hline
\bar c &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -1 &  1 \\
x_1    &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  4 \\
x_2    &  0 &  1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  1 &  2\\
x_3    &  0 &  0 &  1 & -1 &  1 &  1 &  3\\
\end{array}
$$
$$\LARGE\pmb\downarrow$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc|c}
\text{Basis} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & \text{Sol.} \\
\hline
\bar c &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -1 &  1 \\
x_4    &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  4 \\
x_2    &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  2 &  2 &  6 \\
x_3    &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  2 &  2 &  7 \\
\end{array}
$$

**Example of an operation which is not stable but also preserves objective value:**
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc|c}
\text{Basis} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & \text{Sol.} \\
\hline
\bar c &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -1 & -1 &  1 \\
x_1    &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  0 \\
x_2    &  0 &  1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  1 &  2\\
x_3    &  0 &  0 &  1 & -1 &  1 &  1 &  3\\
\end{array}
$$
$$\LARGE\pmb\downarrow$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc|c}
\text{Basis} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & \text{Sol.} \\
\hline
\bar c &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\
x_4    &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  0 \\
x_2    &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  2 &  2 &  2 \\
x_3    &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  2 &  2 &  3 \\
\end{array}
$$

However, in the second case, the solution does not change.

Is there always a path of stable operations from a tableau for an optimal basic feasible solution (BFS) to a tableau for all other optimal BFS? Which of the following are true:

1. For all optimal BFS $X_1$, for all tableaus $T_1$ for $X_1$, for all optimal BFS $X_2$, for all tableaus $T_2$ for $X_2$, there is a path of stable operations from $T_1$ to $T_2$. (I think the answer for this is false.)
2. For all optimal BFS $X_1$, for all tableaus $T_1$ for $X_1$, for all optimal BFS $X_2$, there is a tableau $T_2$ for $X_2$ such that there is a path of stable operations from $T_1$ to $T_2$.
3. For all optimal BFS $X_1$, there is a tableau $T_1$ for $X_1$ such that for all optimal BFS $X_2$, there is a tableau $T_2$ for $X_2$ such that there is a path of stable operations from $T_1$ to $T_2$.

The motivation for this problem is so that we decide when we have exhausted all optimal solutions when searching for them; can we limit our procedure to search only with stable operations on the tableau?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "unstable operation" above *won't give you a different solution*.  You've just replaced the basic variable $x_1 = 0$ by a nonbasic variable $x_4 = 0$, but the solution shown in the above optimal simplex tableau is still $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)^T = (0,2,3,0,0,0)^T$.

Therefore, only "stable operations" with a non-zero variable $x_r \ne 0$ to be replaced by $x_j$ will give you a *different* basic optimal feasible solution.

It's easy to verify that any convex combination of a set of basic optimal feasible solution(s) is still an optimal feasible solution (since the feasible region in a linear program in convex), so the set of optimal feasible solution is convex (i.e. path connected).  Hence, the answer to your question is yes.

---

(Added in response to the edit of the question)

You may just think of the graph so as to visualize your problem.  A basic solution corresponds to an extreme point in the feasible region.  (If $\mathbf x$ is an extreme point, then there doesn't exists two different $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ such that $\mathbf x$ is a convex combination of $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$.)  Form the graph of the set of all optimal feasible solutions of the linear program, and note its convexity (so it's a convex polygon), then eliminate its relative interior point.  Take any two vertices of the remaining boundary points to be $X_1$ and $X_2$ in (1).  Clearly, we can see a path running from $X_1$ to $X_2$ through adjacent vertices.  (Assume that you have $m$ constraints and $n$ decision varibles, and $m < n$.  Choose $n$ vectors in the $m$-by-$m+n$ matrix $A$ to form a basis matrix $B$.  This is similar to choosing hyperplanes (representing the constraints) in $\Bbb R^{m+n}$ and find its intersection.)  This corresponds to a (finite) series of steps of replacing $x_r$ by $x_j$, which is feasible.  Since that's feasible, there exists a pivot operation in one of the simplex tableaux $T_1$ for $X_1$.

Let $y_{00} = \bar c$ be the objective function value, $y_{0j}$ be the $j$-th column of the objective function row (i.e. the row of $\bar c$), $y_{r0} = x_r$ be the $r$-th component of the current solution, and $y_{rj}$ be the $r,j$-th entry in the coefficient matrix.

\begin{matrix}
y_{0j}& y_{00}\\
y_{rj}& y_{r0}
\end{matrix}

In order not to change the value of $y_{00}$ after a pivot operation $y_{00}-\dfrac{y_{r0} y_{0j}}{y_{rj}}$, i.e. $$y_{00}-\dfrac{y_{r0} y_{0j}}{y_{rj}} = y_{00},$$ we have $y_{r0} y_{0j} = 0$.  Since we want to move to another point, we must have $y_{r0} \ne 0$, which implies $y_{0j} = 0$, so the operation must be stable.  Hence (1) is proved.

Comment: But a BFS may have different tableaus associated with it, and the set of BFSs that each tableau is connected to by stable operations may be different. I don't see how convexity can immediately apply here.

Comment: I edited the question to ask it in a more precise manner. Statement $1\implies 2\implies 3$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I think you did not prove (1) (yet). There may not even be a tableau operation to go from one adjacent vertex to another.

Comment: @user1537366 To move from one vertex to an adjacent one, you're actually replacing exactly one hyperplane by another one.  This corresponds to replacing a basic variable by another in the tableau.  The feasibility of this can be proved *geometrically*, and the calculations can be done *arimetically*.

Comment: @user1537366 I see this lecture notes by chance.  I hope this can answer your doubts.  http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/course/lp992/Lecture4.pdf

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I believe there are situations where even if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are adjacent on the polytope and $T_1$ and $T_2$ are corresponding tableaus, we may need to replace more than one hyperplane in order to get from $T_1$ to $T_2$.